# Thinking Sphinx group by, with distinct count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have the following manual Sphinx query (via the mySQL client), that is producing proper results, and I would like to call it through Thinking Sphinx from Rails. For the life of me, I am struggling with how to make a 'distinct' query work in Thinking Sphinx.

```
mysql> select merchant_name, count (distinct part_number) from product_core group by merchant_name;

+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| merchant_name         | count (distinct part_number)            |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|            1962041491 |                                       1 |
|            3208850848 |                                       1 |
|            1043652526 |                                   48754 |
|             770188128 |                                       1 |
|             374573991 |                                   34113 |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Please note: This mySQL query is agaist Sphinx, NOT mySQL. I use the mySQL client to connect to Sphinx, as: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9306`. This works well for debugging/development. My actual db, is Postgres.

Given this, and to add more context, I am attempting to combine a `group_by` in thinking Sphinx, with a `count('Distinct' ...)`.

So, this query works:

```
Product.search group_by: :merchant_name
```

... and, this query works:

```
Product.count ('DISTINCT part_number')
```

... but, this combined query throws an error:

```
Product.search group_by: :merchant_name, count ('DISTINCT part_number')

SyntaxError: (irb):90: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...merchant_name, count ('DISTINCT part_num...
```

Both merchant_name and part_number are defined as attributes.

Environment:

```
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
thinking-sphinx 3.1.4
rails 4.2.4
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.4
```

I have also tried using Facets, but to no avail:

```
Product.search group_by: :merchant_name, facets: :part_number
Product.facets :part_number, group_by: :merchant_name
```

For additional information, and to see if this could be accomplished through a Thinking Sphinx call, here is a basic example. I have one product table (and associated index), that lists both merchants, and their products (I agree, it could be normalized, but its coming in from a data feed, and Sphinx can handle it as is):

```
+-----------------+-------------------+
| merchant        | product           |
+-----------------+-------------------+
|   Best Buy      |   Android phone   |
|   Best Buy      |   Android phone   |
|   Best Buy      |   Android phone   |
|   Best Buy      |   iPhone          |
|   Amazon        |   Android phone   |
|   Amazon        |   iPhone          |
|   Amazon        |   iPhone          |
|   Amazon        |   iPhone          |
|   Amazon        |   Onkyo Receiver  |
+-----------------+-------------------+
```

With Thinking Sphinx, I want to: a) group the rows by merchant, and b) create a “distinct” product count for each group.

The above example, should give the following result:

```
+-----------------+------------------------+
| merchant        | count(DISTINCT product |
+-----------------+------------------------+
|   Best Buy      |   2                    |
|   Amazon        |   3                    |
+-----------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: What's the issue with the query? Is it that merchant_name is returning integers? Or beyond that, are the aggregate values not accurate? What version of Sphinx are you using?

Comment: Pat, my raw query works perfectly against Sphinx via the MySQL client (which proves my indexes and attributes work), I just am not able to write the 'district' portion of the query into a ThinkingSphinx call.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to run this query through a model's search call, because that's set up to always return instances of a model, whereas what you're wanting is raw results. The following code should do the trick:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Connection.take do |connection|
  result = connection.execute <<-SQL
  SELECT merchant_name, COUNT(distinct part_number)
  FROM product_core
  GROUP BY merchant_name
  SQL
  result.to_a
end
```

Or, I think this will work to go through a normal `search` call:

```
Product.search(
  select:     "merchant_name, COUNT(distinct part_number) AS count",
  group_by:   :merchant_name,
  middleware: ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::RAW_ONLY
)
```

Comment: Hi Pat, thanks for your timely reply! I was in the process of writing my own connection object, but prefer to use the connection already created and managed by Thinking Sphinx.

Comment: Now that I have this working, I see that you must create your own CRC values for my attributes, which are already converted to bigint. I am able to map your sphinx_internal_id back to my id, but just to ask one more time, is there a way to create the same group_by merchant_name / count unique part_number results, using your Thinking Sphinx methods?

Am I missing something basic w/ TS?

Comment: Martin, I'm not quite following: in what way is the above query not what you're after? Or better yet, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Pat, I just added a simple example at the bottom my initial posting. Please let me know, if you need more info. Appreciate your support!!

Comment: And the issue is that merchant_name is being returned as an integer representation, instead of a string?

Comment: No. Ultimately, I would like to do the group_by and distinct count using 
Thinking Sphinx functions, vs the raw SphinxQL query. With your help, I am now able to use the SphinxQL, but I would like to do something like this: 'Product.search group_by: :merchant_name, count ('DISTINCT part_number')'

Comment: Pat, sorry if I am causing confusion here. Initially, when I could not get TS functions to work, I asked for (and received) the ability to pass SphinxQL directly through TS (Thank you!). Now that this is working (and I have your attention), I would like to see if in fact there is a direct TS solution. Make more sense?

Comment: Just added what I think is the solution to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks Pat, this approach works as well. Have you ever considered writing a book around Thinking Sphinx? I love the product, and have used it on multiple projects, but don’t find it documented well. Andrew Aksyonoff’s “Introduction to Search with Sphinx”, is a perfect example of what you could create. At only 150 pages, its a comprehensive overview of Sphinx. You could publish a companion book for Thinking Sphinx, and bridge the gap between Sphinx and Rails! Perhaps, I could be a co-author!

Comment: I did write one, but it was some time ago (2008!), and sadly is no longer available (Peepcode got bought by Pluralsight, and while the video podcasts were kept online, PDFs were not). http://freelancing-gods.com/2008/10/24/thinking-sphinx-pdf-at-peepcode.html

Comment: Perhaps an updated version 2 is in the works, covering TS3 and perhaps, upcoming Rails 5?